# Airflow Datasets consumer collision when catchup=True

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm new to Airflow and I'm trying to understand how to avoid collisions when using the Datasets mechanism with catchup=True parameter.

Setup:
1 Producer
1 Dataset
1 Consumer

Say the Producer runs hourly and overwrites a file in S3 which defines the Dataset.
The consumer will be triggered, read params from the modified file and use them in the dag run.
The thing is, if previous runs should be triggered upon catchup=True, I'm not sure how this behavior may affect the dag runs that run simultaneously as this file will be overwritten unexpectedly.

Is there any mechanism that could protect from this happening which I'm not aware of?
Or maybe I should use a different mechanism for such use case?